# SharePoint Custom WebService and Authentication

Tags: 2010, web-services

I have developed a SharePoint 2010 Custom Werbservice and its deployed inside
_layouts/CustomWS/MyWebService.asmx

so if I try to access through browser like http://portal.mydomain.com/_layouts/CustomWS/MyWebService.asmx it shows the methods...This webservice is basically performing an integration with 3rd party application "Oracle EBS" and we send data to Oracle EBS and we receive data from Oracle EBS and write into sharepoint 2010 lists.

My question is that if I will give this link to Oracle EBS guys and if they want to send data through one of my webservice method can they face authentication issues or they will be accessing the werbservice without any problem. Let me know how I can let them consume this service freely.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it depends on the level of access they have to your SharePoint web application.If they can view pages under /_layouts, they should be able to see the web service as well.